# ASP.NET MVC direct user to a View from a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASp.NET MVC 3.

Whilst in a View, how do I redirect the User to a View that's in a different Controller altogether?

I can do: `@Html.ActionLink("Go Here", "Index")` but I want to direct the user to an Index view of a different Controller.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another overload from ActionLink

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070%28v=vs.108%29

usage

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go Here", "Index", "<YourOtherController>")
```

Answer (score 1):

@Html.ActionLink(string LinkText, string ActionName, String ControllerName)

There are a lot of prameters to choose from. Type @HTML.ActionLink( and they will show up. Navigate between them using the up and down button.